# Instruments: __Abort_with_payload

Tags: c, macos, profiling, instruments

I've been trying to profile a C program using Instruments.

If I run the program manually from terminal, it takes around 15s to execute.
The problem is that if I try to run it with instruments, in the profile section I get..

[image: Profiling C program Image]

Any ideas what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: In my case lib: HelpshiftOSX.framework wasn't linked correctly so in runtime fail to load